# Does OS X Mavericks have Activation Lock like iOS 7?

Tags: macos, icloud, find-my-mac

I have bought a used MacBook Pro Retina, and after three mounths using it, I think I could do a clean install for my Mac. However, if it has an activation lock will that stop me using my Mac after a clean install as it could ask me for an iCloud account?

Comment: There is no activation lock in the Mavericks operating system, but, since you got it as used, better check for 3d party apps on your system. Also for example, the Apple Store, iTunes user/password needs to be yours.

Comment: Any newer OS X than the one that came with your system may need to be repurchased with your own Apple ID.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Macs do not have Activation Lock.**

The only Find My iPhone lock that is present on OS X is the force lock from selecting the device in the Find My iPhone device list and clicking Lock. Simply reinstalling OS X can't lock a Mac unlike iOS Activation Lock.

Note that Find My Mac will register the serial number (or other hardware identifier) for the purposes of recording a single Mac and that reinstalling OS X will not remove this identifier from Apple's servers and may show a "Find My Mac is already in use" message if you attempt to set it up in the future.